# Does luarocks management have "./node_modules" equivalent for projects?

Tags: lua, luarocks

In NodeJS/NPM, you can create a `package.json` and run `npm install` to install all your dependencies in a folder within your project: `./node_modules`. (A project can be an app or another module/package.)

Ruby also has a "bundler" system (using a .bundle file) that keeps track of gems specific to a dir (ie project).

Does LuaRocks have similar conventions? Or is it recommeneded to install everything to `/usr` or `$HOME`?

So far I've been able to get similiar functionality, but I have to create a custom LuaRocks config file and specify `--tree=my_local_lua_rocks_dir` every time I want to install a rock. Granted, I can always create a bash script. The point is that it seems I'm going against a convention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to install rocks into a directory under the current directory, using the `--tree` flag:

```sh
luarocks install --tree ./lua_modules lpeg
```

And then you have to configure your `package.path` and `package.cpath` variables in Lua (settable via `LUA_PATH` and `LUA_CPATH` environment variables) so it finds the modules installed inside it. There are several ways to do this conveniently: this [tutorial explains how to do it, with more examples](http://leafo.net/guides/customizing-the-luarocks-tree.html).

Comment: Thanks very much. This answered cleared up a lot of my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using [Vert](http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/#vert), I've decided to just edit the LuaRocks config file:

1. In `/etc/luarocks/config.lua` :

   ```
   rocks_servers = {
    [[http://rocks.moonscript.org/]],
    [[http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks]]
   }

   rocks_trees = {
    [[/usr/local]],
    [[./my_dir]]
   }
   ```

   `./my_dir` is relative to the `pwd` you're in, not to the location of the config file. Of course, change `my_dir` to whatever you want.

   "The order of the `rock_trees` matters:  When installing rocks, LuaRocks tries to pick a location to store the rock starting from the bottom of the list; when loading rocks in runtime, LuaRocks scans from the top of the list." **From**: http://luarocks.org/en/Config_file_format
2. Then in your `.bashrc`:

   ```
   eval `luarocks path`
   export PATH=$PATH:my_dir/bin
   ```
3. However, for certain commands you now have to specify the tree or it will give you a confusing error:

   ```
   luarocks make --tree=my_dir
   ```